# lxc-kill: failed to get the init pid

Tags: docker, lxc

I got a problem ,it seems that the container is already stopped. Cause I ping the container's ip, and got no answer.
lxc-info indicate that the process is STOP

```
[root@matrix-node04 mnt]# lxc-info -n f3a939113d6e12450829a2dc76be3c761b818e63fbd33df513772e6e4485565e
state:   STOPPED
pid:        -1
```

But docker ps indicate the process is still running

```
[root@matrix-node04 mnt]# docker ps | grep f3a939113d6e
f3a939113d6e        c69436ea2169                                           /bin/sh -c '/usr/loc   4 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks                                                                                 d-mcl-354_lisx_test_kr22-n-3
```

can I use lxc-start to manualy start the container ? I tried the following cmd

```
[root@matrix-node04 mnt]# lxc-start -n f3a939113d6e12450829a2dc76be3c761b818e63fbd33df513772e6e4485565e -f /srv/docker/containers/f3a939113d6e12450829a2dc76be3c761b818e63fbd33df513772e6e4485565e/config.lxc
lxc-start: No such file or directory - failed to get real path for '/srv/docker/devicemapper/mnt/f3a939113d6e12450829a2dc76be3c761b818e63fbd33df513772e6e4485565e/rootfs'
lxc-start: failed to pin the container's rootfs
lxc-start: failed to spawn 'f3a939113d6e12450829a2dc76be3c761b818e63fbd33df513772e6e4485565e'
```

Has someone met this ?